# Mybatis When test condition with Internal query

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am looking for a query where i can use either internal query returned value or direct SQL in `when test=` in Mybatis.

```
 <foreach item="ID"
             index="index"
             collection="selectionIds"
             separator=";">
    UPDATE TABLE_1 SET
    ACT_IND ='N', upd_by = 1234
    WHERE SLCT_ID = #{ID}
    AND rem= select REM from TABLE_1 where SLCT_ID=#{ID}
    <choose>
        <when test="rem == 3">
            AND Bbsid=#{nsid}
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            AND asid=#{asid}
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
    </foreach>
```

From the above query, how can i get the rem value and use in when condition.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by perm value?

Comment: Modified my post, it's rem not prem.

Comment: Did you try `AND rem= select REM as SUBQUERY_REM from TABLE_1 where SLCT_ID=#{ID}` and then `<when test="SUBQUERY_REM == 3">` ?

Comment: It is not working as it is expecting SUBQUERY_REM as input parameter.

Comment: And how about you move the `<choose>` condition to separate sql fragment and include it like `<include refid="someId"><property name="REM_PARAM" value="SUBQUERY_REM"/></include>` ?

Comment: @rakeeee You cannot use a column value in the test condition of `<if />` or `<when />`.  Those conditions are evaluated when building the SQL statement (i.e. before executing the statement). It might be possible to achieve it in SQL level, but I'm having difficulty understanding your goal from the posted statement. Could you explain the SELECT part and the UPDATE part separately in the question (i.e. how would you do it using two SQLs instead of one)?

Comment: At last solved this issue by separating the queries. Thanks a lot for your help.